# Update Statements with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Apologies as I'm fairly new to SQL, but I'm wondering if it's possible to join two tables in an Update statement, while sourcing the column to actually be updated from a *third* table. For example, let's say I have a simple "emp" table (**emp_unid**, first_name, last_name, mgr_unid), a "dept" table (**dept_unid**, dept_name), and a third "link" table (**link_id**, emp_unid, dept_unid).

The company decides to transfer all employees with a surname of "Ferguson" or "Malone" from the Exports department to the Imports department, so we need to update the corresponding records in the "link" table using the emp_unids from "emp", and using the corresponding dept_unid from "dept".

Theoretically, I would want to write an update statement something like below:

```
UPDATE link l, emp e
    SET l.dept_unid = (SELECT dept_unid FROM dept 
                       WHERE dept_name = 'IMPORTS')
    WHERE l.emp_unid = e.emp_unid
    AND e.last_name IN ('FERGUSON', 'MALONE')
```

I've tried flipping around the WHERE clause to before the SET clause, I've tried using an explicit join, I've tried writing this completely devoid of aliases, but I can't make this work -- I keep getting "ORA-00971: missing SET keyword". From what I've read/experimented with, Oracle does not seem to like updating multiple tables in one statement, but in actuality, I'm just trying to update one table, while referencing two other tables.

Am I missing something simple, or is there a more clever way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE link l
SET l.dept_unid = (SELECT dept_unid FROM dept 
                   WHERE dept_name = 'IMPORTS')
WHERE l.emp_unid = (select e.emp_unid
                    from emp e
                    where e.last_name IN ('FERGUSON', 'MALONE'))
```